# Toggle Switch: Change cursor pointer

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Toggle switch from this link: http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switch/bootstrap.html.

I want the selected part (with Blue batch) to be `cursor:default` and unselected (with white batch) to be `cursor: pointer`.

This is my HTML code.

```
<div class="switch-toggle well">
    <input id="week" name="view" type="radio" checked>
    <label for="week" onclick="">Week</label>

    <input id="month" name="view" type="radio">
    <label for="month" onclick="">Month</label>

    <a class="btn btn-primary"></a>
</div>
```

My js fiddle link is.. http://jsfiddle.net/Wd2rL/

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to move the "blue layer" div on top of "week" and "month" div's, make it semi transparent and then set its cursor to default, and then you set "week" and "month" div's cursor to pointer.

Bonus: it's CSS only, where no extra scriptings is needed

UPDATE

Following changes made:  (fiddle update:  http://jsfiddle.net/Wd2rL/9/ )

```
#weeklbl, #monthlbl {cursor:pointer}   // added as both css and id's on labels

.switch-toggle a {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 0;
  z-index: 6;                // changed from 1
    opacity: 0.5;            // added
    cursor:default;          // added
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%; }
```

UPDATE 2

After some more thinking, and if you don't care about older IE (8 and lower ver. .. and you do already by using css animation), you can use the :checked selector to alter the z-index of the elements. This means no transparency and full colored div's/text can be used.

Sample of with/without `:checked` selector:

```
#week, #month {
  z-index: 6;
}
#week:checked {
  z-index: 1;
}
#month:checked {
  z-index: 1;
}
```

This solution will solve the tricky part here, as the layer layout is the trick, how to slide the colored div under a text and at the same time having where to click above the text .

This means, in this case, the checkbox is on top until it's checked, and checked it will be placed at bottom (and cursor:pointer/clickable area is hidden).

And if a user has IE8, it will still work, but with visible cursor:pointer on both marked/unmarked div's

Comment: I really try this but could you provide the code because I think it wont work.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer. I applied this now and its working but when I am providing label color as white got hide.

jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/EFqek/2/

Comment: Your new ccs don't have my above changes .. but even so, using white text will look strange as it hardly is visible on the grey label background.

Comment: Updated my answer .. now you have all you need and only has to apply it yourself ... :)

Comment: Thanks for solving this issue.
I used this
First made all label cursor: pointer
.switch-toggle input:checked + label {
    cursor: default;
}

Answer (score 2):

Do like this:)

```
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.a').mouseenter(function(){
  if($(this).attr("val")=="0")
  {
    $(this).css("cursor","pointer");
  }
 else
  {
    $(this).css("cursor","default");
  }
 });
 $('.a').click(function(){
 $(".a").attr('val','0');
 $(this).css("cursor","default");
 $(this).attr("val","1"); 
 });
 });
```

[**Here is a fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Wd2rL/7/)

Comment: This is very good solution, but not so useful as He wants a code in  CSS only.

Comment: Yes I want solution in css only

Answer (score 0):

Well, After working a lot I have managed to find you simple CSS solution, Hope you will like it.

as per PellePenna Solution I have manage to update z-index.

```
.switch-toggle label{
    cursor:pointer;
}
.switch-toggle a{
    cursor:default;
    opacity:0.5;
    z-index:3;
    background-color:#208bca;
}
```

This is link to JSFiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/EFqek/

Comment: Thank you for using my way of thinking. Proves my "brain" is still working :)